# Transform 2D array to object and use first array element as key

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine I have this array of arrays:

```
myData = [
  ["wantThisAsKey1",someElement1,anotherElement1],
  ["wantThisAsKey2",someElement2,anotherElement2]
]
```

I need to convert this array to an object where the first element of each array is used as the key:

```
myDataObject = {
  "wantThisAsKey1": [someElement1,anotherElement1],
  "wantThisAsKey2": [someElement2,anotherElement2],
}
```

How can I do this in a general way, something like `myDataObject = convertToObject(myData)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let myData = [
  ["wantThisAsKey1","someElement1","anotherElement1"],
  ["wantThisAsKey2","someElement2","anotherElement2"]
];
let myDataObject = convertToObject(myData);
console.log(myDataObject);

function convertToObject(data){
     let res = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          res[data[i][0]] = data[i].slice(1);
     return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can combine the arrays reduce function with destructuring assignment:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
myData = [
  ["wantThisAsKey1", 1, 2],
  ["wantThisAsKey2", 2, 3]
]

const newobject = myData.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    const [key, ...rest] = elem;
    acc[key] = rest
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(newobject);

// Result: { wantThisAsKey1: [ 1, 2 ], wantThisAsKey2: [ 2, 3 ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using reduce here. like this.

```
const result = myData.reduce( (result, ele) => {
  const [key, ...other] = ele
  result[key] = other
  return result
 }, {})

// output = { wantThisAsKey1: [ 'someElement1', 'anotherElement1' ], wantThisAsKey2: [ 'someElement2', 'anotherElement2' ] }
```